# cakephp : testing redirect

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit

I am trying tying to test redirection in my unit test code.  Controller Code is:

```
public function redirection() {
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    return ;
}
```

and test code is :

```
public function testRedirection() {
    $return_var = $this->testAction('/users/redirection', array('return'=>'vars'));
    $results = $this->headers['Location'];
    var_dump( $this->headers['Location']);
}
```

and output:

```
string(55) "http://localhost/var/www/html/cakephp/app/Console/users"
```

My question is how can I get rid of the entire string "var/www/html/cakephp/app/Console", and secondly why it does not have 'index' in it ?

Answer (score 2):

Modify your controller to something like this

```
public function redirection() {
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

The reason being (quoting the book)

> When testing actions that contain redirect() and other code following the redirect it is generally a good idea to return when redirecting. The reason for this, is that redirect() is mocked in testing, and does not exit like normal. And instead of your code exiting, it will continue to run code following the redirect. For example:

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController {
    public function add() {
       if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Article->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
        // more code
    }
}
```

> When testing the above code, you will still run // more code even when the redirect is reached. Instead, you should write the code like:

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController {
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Article->save($this->request->data)) {
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    // more code
    }
}
```

In this case // more code will not be executed as the method will return once the redirect is reached.

Comment: You can also use a [mock](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#using-mocks-with-testaction) if needed.

Comment: I think its not an issue that some code is still running after the redirect. as you can see return statement right after redirect.

However I tried what you suggested with no success. If I test using http::/localhost/test.php  , I do get values right. Testing from command line does not set the host , and uses the path of the file in headers. I like command line better so I am still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the string `"var/www/html/cakephp/app/Console"`, add the following code in the `setUp()` method of your test class:

```
Configure::write('App.base', '');
```

You can also control the value of the prefix "http://localhost" using:

```
Configure::write('App.fullBaseUrl', 'http://example.net');
```